# New Appbuilder: Crash when hightlight text > right click in Chrome

Tags: krl

In the new app builder, when you are in Chrome, and you highlight some text and right click it to copy it, it kills Chrome and you have to relaunch your browser, so all of your progress is lost. I keep forgetting to just ctrl + c, and it literally restarts my browser like once every 10 mins. So, I keep losing work.

Comment: Because this isn't really a programming question, it's probably better suited as an email to support@kynetx.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Ace Editor, the editor that AppBuilder uses. Bug info here:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/100

There is some indication that the newest release of Chrome does fix the problem. Can you test and confirm?

(Oh, and to agree with Mike Grace, this really is a better email to support then a question on SO.)